PCI Audit: OpenSSH Authentication Bypass Vulnerability (CVE-2023-51767)
Today I ran an Qualys PCI audit on one of my servers. It listed some vulnerabilities, but many of them are caused of a simple version check, so "false positive" I think.
But one vulnerability is OpenSSH Authentication Bypass Vulnerability (CVE-2023-51767).
On https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2023-51767 it says:

as of 2024-02-02, there is no mitigation for this issue. Marking as
deferred

And still it looks like as if there is no fix for this.
Except of deactivating ssh: What would you do to get this server PCI compliant?
Currently using Ubuntu 20.04 - but even with 24.04 (which is currently not possible on my hoster) it does not seems to be fixed?!

What Ubuntu version are you using?

Ubuntu 20.04 - added this in my question

Forwarded the inquiry over to my friends on the Security team, we'll see if there's a way to fix this.  Note I don't see any patches in Upstream OpenSSH for this so it's possible OpenSSH has no fix for this yet.

Additionally note the NVD data on this issue: "OpenSSH through 9.6, when common types of DRAM are used, might allow row hammer attacks (for authentication bypass) because the integer value of authenticated in mm_answer_authpassword does not resist flips of a single bit. NOTE: this is applicable to a certain threat model of attacker-victim co-location in which the attacker has user privileges." (emphasis mine)

Additionally, it's been suggested that this exploit is not demonstrated against stock OpenSSH nor any known real-world deployment but a modified OpenSSH and a non-real-world configuration setup

I'm curious to hear what you have to report! And yes, it sounds like that's more of a theoretical security vulnerability... But what should I do with the audit if there is no fix?

from my contacts on the Security team this is a hardware problem.  rowhammer attacks are really not possible to completely mitigate.  These audits SHOULD have the capacity for you to explain and justify why it's failing - the answer is because "This is a primarily theoretical attack, and default use cases and SSHd settings have not been proven to be affected. Additionally, rowhammer attacks are impossible to fully protect against, and because there is no patch in this from OpenSSH, this cannot (yet) be fixed."

Don't forget the base auditing tools are pretty dumb and don't take into accounts where "We can't fix this yet because there's no fix yet" and such

Thank you very much for this information!

I reached out to my Security team contacts and we had a bit of a discussion with additional bug links, and details from my dive into this.
Per the Security Team, they made revisions to the CVE on the Ubuntu CVE tracker.  Marc Deslauriers, a long time member of the Ubuntu Security Team, readdressed and rereviewed the CVE and related links from the NVD and other upstream sources and ended up with this conclusion which is now reflected on the Ubuntu CVE tracker:

The researchers used a modified version of sshd to make this
vulnerability easier to demonstrate. There is no indication
the openssh package in Ubuntu can be exploited in the same way.
The upstream OpenSSH developers have chosen to ignore this issue
as this vulnerability isn't exploitable in practice, and needs
to be addressed by the hardware platform, not in OpenSSH itself.
Since there is nothing actionable here for Ubuntu, I am marking
this issue as ignored.

(emphasis mine)

Normally PCI/DSS, etc. policy scans are dumb, but the actual compliance policy can be stated that there are reasons that certain issues go Unfixed.  You can use something like this as justification for this one being 'unfixed' in the evaluation should you create a full report on this:

Upstream OpenSSH developers have checked this vulnerabilty and the paper that was written on it. The researchers in question use a modified sshd to make this vulnerability easier to demonstrate, meaning that the stock OpenSSH binaries are NOT PROVEN to be affected by this vulnerability.
Additionally, this issue is primarily a hardware platform issue, not an OpenSSH issue, as row-hammer attacks need to be addressed by the hardware platform. OpenSSH has in turn chosen to ignore this issue, and because there is nothing that can be done in Ubuntu or other OSes for this, the identified vulnerability is not fixable.


Requesting a "false positive" was successful. Thanks for your support!!
